# How can I add a message after the "last login" shown when starting san ssh connection?

Tags: ssh

I can't find how to add a message after the "last login..." line on my Ubuntu 14.04. I can edit everything before using the files in `/etc/update-motd.d/` and I can show/hide the last login message using the config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

But how can I add something after that?.  Or, alternatively, how can I edit the last login message?

Comment: Why do you need the message to appear _after_ the last login line? What are you trying to achieve? There might be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to run a command in the `bashrc` for SSH connections:

In `/etc/bash.bashrc` (for system-wide) or `~/.bashrc` (for your user only), append these lines:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_TTY ]]
then
    # Do stuff to get the output.
    echo "Hi, SSH user $USER!"
fi
```

I don't know how to edit the last login message, but you can disable it and simulate it by using the [`last` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/last.1.html), and the filter and modify the output according to your need.

Comment: Using your solution with the ~/.bashrc is working fine.  But not with the /etc/bash.bashrc.

Comment: @tweetysat i use the same test to set the prompt, and it usually works fine in the system-wide way.

Comment: I made again some tries with /etc/bash.bashrc.  Suppose I added a line to display time. I'm connecting via ssh with user toto.  Nothing displays.  I'm doing su toto.  The time is displayed.

Comment: I think I have to put it in /etc/profile for system-wide and in ~/.bashrc for user only